# Bootstrap css map breaking request rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rspec

I have a default rspec for a simple request

```
  describe "GET /clients" do
    it "works! (now write some real specs)" do
      get clients_path
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end
  end
```

This fails when application layout tries to get the stylesheets:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: Invalid CSS after "...":3,"sources":[": expected "|", was ""bootstrap.css"..."
  (in ...:/.../app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
(sass):1
./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___320761601_41133324'
./spec/requests/clients_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
```

I'm guessing it's trying to render bootstrap.css.map.css as CSS? Is there any way around this?

**UPDATE**: Including `application.css`

```
 /*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap.min
 *= require custom
 *= require table_sort
 *= require bootstrap-multiselect
 */


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src: url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
    src: url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: Can you share your application.css file?

Answer (score 0):

Removing `bootstrap.css.map` file solved the issue.

Comment: I ended up moving my *.map to the public folder as an workaround. But still, does not seems to be the best approach to choose.